# ValidatorException exception struts validation framework

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

I am getting the following error while submitting my form using struts validation frame work

Exception Stack Trace
org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException: Unknown field Axles Spacing Distance in testForm

Please help us in resolving this issue.

Comment: I bet somewhere you've referenced a field called "Axles Spacing Distance", which is a wildly unlikely property name. In the future, consider actually including relevant portions of your validation file so someone could actually help.

Answer (score 0):

it is the problem of java code. we are trying to retrieve the componet by name. i have changes code to component by ID. it is working fine